# Is there a way to programmatically close all open NSPopovers on key event, instead of mouse event?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover

My Cocoa application can have several popovers that open.
If you click anywhere else, the currently opened popover will close (normal behavior)

However, we also have a hotkey that changes the state of the application, and we would like the popovers to close, similar to how a mouse event would close it.

Some of the popovers have textfields for user input, and I don't want to just override my popover class to listen for this specific hotkey to close, but that's the only idea I have right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with an interesting solution that actually is pretty safe, as far as the application state goes.

I traverse the responder chain, looking for NSPopover, and if I find one, I pass the `-cancelOperation` message (which is sent on ESC key pressed)

This safely closes my popovers

```
 +   NSWindowController* windowController = [MyMainWindowController sharedWindowController];
 +   NSResponder *responder = [[windowController window] firstResponder];
 +   while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]))
 +   {
 +      if( [responder isKindOfClass:[NSPopover class]] )
 +      {
 +         [[windowController window] cancelOperation:nil];
 +         break;
 +      }
 +   }
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to send a custom `NSNotification` when your application changes state, and have each `NSPopover` listen for that notification and close itself.